# Do older Android versions support SHA-256?

Tags: certificates

We are updating our certs. for our MDM program, and that includes rolling out SHA-256. That being said, do all Android versions support SHA-256 (especially 4.0.3 and 4.1.1)?

Comment: According to the [Globalsign support pages](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility) SHA-256 certificates work in general since Android 1.0 and full support since 2.2.